# Serializing single instance in Django

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have a simple "Driver" Django model with fields "id", "phone", and "address". I added a serializer and a request handler to return the last driver from the database as shown below. 
The serializer returns empty data when i pass a single instance driver object. However, it returns the last driver as a list if i pass the same object as a list and set many = True. Any ideas how can i get the serializer working with instance parameter instead of wrapping it in a list?

```
        def get_last_driver(request):
            last_driver_object = Driver.objects.last()
            # This returns empty data {"last_driver": null}
            last_driver_data = DriverSerializer(last_driver_object).data
            # This results a list containing one object : {"last_driver": [{"id": 3, "phone": "0123456", "address": "DemoSteet 12"}]}
            last_driver_data = DriverSerializer([last_driver_object], many=True).data
            return JsonResponse({"last_driver": last_driver_data})

class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Driver
         fields = ("id", "phone", "address")

class Driver(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='driver')
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Comment: It should work fine with a single model instance. Double check that `last()` actually returned an object when you tested your serializer. Also check your code snippet. Your `return` is misplaced. Also is that a serializer from `django-rest-framework` ?

Comment: @trixn Indeed It is a django rest framework serializer and I misplaced the return statement when I post the question, but it was in the correct place in my project. I debugged the flow and the there is valid data in it. Besides, the second run wouldn't have returned filled data if last() had returned empty. I updated the output in the code snippet above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your DB doesn't contain any data. So, add some response while using API, as

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


def get_last_driver(request):
    if not SampleModel.objects.exists():  # if atleast one object is there
        return Response(data={"message": "There is no 'Driver' object in DB"})

    last_driver_object = Driver.objects.last()
    serializer = DriverSerializer(last_driver_object)
    return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

and in your serializers, there no need of a **`return`** statement, because `return` are used in `functions`. Hence your serializer would be like,

```
class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ("id", "phone", "address")
```

Comment: Indeed, I misplaced the return statement when I post the question, but it was in the correct place in my project. I debugged the flow and the there is valid data in it. I also used the exists() function and a valid data exist. Besides, the second run wouldn't have returned filled data if last() had returned empty. I updated the output in the code snippet above.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: I tried ur code. In the link below is a snapshot of my debug session which shows a valid data  exist but the serializer is returning null. Debug snapshot in https://ibb.co/mVqnaz

Comment: {"last_driver": null}

Comment: What is the output of `print(last_driver_object.__dict__)`

Comment: {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001F4CE90D438>, 'id': 4, 'user_id': 18, 'avatar': 'wonder woman', 'phone': '987654', 'address': 'Mordor'}

Comment: Use Response class as exactly mentioned in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178246/discussion-between-dangila-and-jerin-peter-george).

Comment: I downgraded my djangorestframework package to previous version and it works. Then I upgraded to the latest 3.8.2 version, and it worked. I guess there was something wrong with my restframework installation.